# Cursor definition gives error 1064, but the base select works ok. Where's the error?

Tags: mysql, cursor, mysql-error-1064

I wrote the following code - which is part of a bigger stored procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CGF;
CREATE PROCEDURE CGF( target_id INT )
BEGIN
  DECLARE atual INT;
  Declare  prior INT;
  DECLARE perc_dif DECIMAL(18,2);
  DECLARE dumpdate DATETIME;
  DECLARE done SMALLINT;


  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_Result;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_Result 
  (
    load_date DATETIME,
    likes_fans INT,
    perc_dif DECIMAL(18,2)
  );

  DECLARE csr_alvo CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
      th.likes,
      th.dump_date
    FROM 
      target_history th
      INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT 
          max(th.dump_date) AS dump_date
        FROM 
          target_history thi
        WHERE 
          th.target_id = thi.target_id
        GROUP BY (CAST(dump_date AS DATE))
        )  t
        ON th.dump_date = t.dump_date;
END;
```

If I comment the `DECLARE CURSOR` part, the procedure is compiled ok and created. The `SELECT` used, when executed outside the declaration, works with no problems.

What I'm doing wrong? Based on what I can get from internet, the syntax **appears** to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `DECLARE` after a `BEGIN`. You can either move yours up to the top next to your other declares, or wrap it with a `BEGIN ... END;` block.